# Facebook links to non existent featured article in joomla

Tags: facebook, url, joomla

I have a site www.line4ever.com, first time I wrote url in facebook it shows a featured demo article of the template.  I erased it from the site, and wrote an article with the information.  But facebook keeps showing the now non existent featured article.

I thought it was a cache, but three days later I still have the problem.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look using the facebook debugger tool. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.line4ever.com

You can see what errors there might be and what the cached version of the page looks like. Although 3 days does seem like a long time for a cache, there's probably more factors Facebook take into account (popularity etc.) before they invalidate a cache